# Pandas shows False irrespective of the logical operation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, boolean

```
wordtags.Count.head()
Out[44]: 
0    6
1    5
2    1
3    1
4    2
Name: Count, dtype: object

wordtags.Count==6
Out[45]: 
0        False
1        False
2        False
3        False
4        False
5        False
6        False
7        False
8        False
```

Pandas shows `False` irrespective of the logical operation.
It is should be `True` for the first row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dtype: object` says that `Count` is of string (`object`) dtype, so try this instead:

```
wordtags.Count=='6'
```

you can cast it to numeric dtype:

```
wordtags['Count'] = pd.to_numeric(wordtags['Count'], errors='coerce')
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a column of integers that are strings, I'd recommend converting them to integer.

```
wordtags['Count'] = wordtags['Count'].astype(int)
```

And now,

```
wordtags.Count == 6
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
Name: Count, dtype: bool
```